# abort the whole transaction when a single function has failed in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a main function to call each child function.  I want the function rollback if one of child function throw an error.  The main function work fine if something go wrong with it and the transaction will stopped but error message didn't post in the errorlog table.  I want if something goes wrong with the child function, I do care the transaction of the main function will stop and roll back all not proceed the rest of successful child function.

here is my script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ecisdrdm.pr_merge_staging_tables(    OUT v_ret text)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE  AS $BODY$

DECLARE

    v_errorcode      text;   v_errormsg       varchar(512);    v_module         varchar(32) = 'pr_merge_staging_tables';    v_host          varchar(32) = inet_server_addr();

begin

    PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Starting MERGE Process' );       begin   v_ret = '0';

    if v_ret = '0' then            ---     --- Perform the merge on APPLICATION_CDIM    ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_APPLICATION_CDIM' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_application_cdim();         -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_APPLICATION_CDIM' );
            end if;


    ---  2. STG_BNFT_CURR_FACT  ----
        if v_ret = '0' then

    ---     --- Perform the merge on BNFT_CURR_FACT     ---

        PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_BNFT_CURR_FACT' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_bnft_curr_fact();       -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION

        PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_BNFT_CURR_FACT' );
            end if;


    ----    --  3. STG_BNFT_FACT    ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on BNFT_FACT  ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_BNFT_FACT' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_bnft_fact();        -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION        v_ret = '0';
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_BNFT_FACT' );       end if;


    ----    --  4. STG_BNFT_HIST_ACTN_LDIM  ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on BNFT_HIST_ACTN_LDIM    ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_BNFT_HIST_ACTN_LDIM ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_bnft_hist_actn_ldim ();         -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_BNFT_HIST_ACTN_LDIM ' );

    end if;


    ----    --  5. STG_CNTRY_ST_CDIM    ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on CNTRY_ST_CDIM  ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0','Started merging STG_CNTRY_ST_CDIM ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_cntry_st_cdim();        -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_CNTRY_ST_CDIM ');       end if;


    ----    --  6. STG_FRM_CDIM     ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on FRM_CDIM   ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_FRM_CDIM ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_frm_cdim();         -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                        PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_FRM_CDIM ' );       end if;


    ----    --  7. STG_G28  ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on G28    ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0','Started merging STG_G28 ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_g28();      -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_G28 ' );        end if;


    ----    --  8. STG_PRTY_CDIM    ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on PRTY_CDIM  ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_PRTY_CDIM ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_prty_cdim();        -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_PRTY_CDIM ' );      end if;


    ----    --  9. STG_PRTY_TYP_LKUP    ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on PRTY_TYP_LKUP  ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_PRTY_TYP_LKUP ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_prty_typ_lkup();        -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0','Finished merging STG_ PRTY_TYP_LKUP ' );      end if;

    ----    --  10. STG_R2I864  ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on R2I864     ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_R2I864 ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_r2i864();       -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished merging STG_R2I864 ' );         end if;

    ----    --  11. STG_REMIT   ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on REMIT  ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_REMIT ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_remit();        -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0','Finished merging STG_ REMIT ' );      end if;

    ----    --  12. STG_SRC_SYS_CDIM    ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on SRC_SYS_CDIM   ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0','Started merging STG_SRC_SYS_CDIM ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_src_sys_cdim();         -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0',  'Finished merging STG_SRC_SYS_CDIM ' );      end if;


    ----    --  13. STG_SVC_CTR_CDIM    ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on SVC_CTR_CDIM   ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Started merging STG_SVC_CTR_CDIM ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_svc_ctr_cdim();         -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0','Finished merging STG_SVC_CTR_CDIM ' );        end if;


    ----    --  14. STG_USCIS_EMP_CDIM  ----
        if v_ret = '0' then     ---     --- Perform the merge on USCIS_EMP_CDIM     ---
            PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0','Started merging STG_USCIS_EMP_CDIM ' );
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_uscis_emp_cdim_cd ();       -- TODO: INVESTIGATE HOW TO RECEIVE THE OUT PARAMETER RETRUNED FROM FUNCTION
                PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0','Finished merging STG_USCIS_EMP_CDIM ' );      end if;


---
--- This does the final commit or rollback for the entire merge process.
---

    if v_errorcode = '0' then       PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished MERGE PROCESS - COMMIT WORK' );         /*  commit work; */     else        PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, '0', 'Finished MERGE PROCESS - ROLLBACK WORK ' );      /*  rollback work; */       ROLLBACK;       end if;

----
--- Exception error handler
----

exception    when others then
        v_errorcode := SQLSTATE;
        v_errormsg  := SQLERRM;         v_ret       := v_errorcode;

    PERFORM ecisdrdm.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, v_host, v_module, v_errorcode, v_errormsg);   end;

END; $BODY$;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSvC4.png)

I do want to get the notification It's violated that that happened at the application level, write into the errorlog table and roll back no matter what function to fail, not the just continuing the rest of transaction function.

Answer (score 1):

From your cascade of words I assume that you want to undo everything that happened in the function and log an error message. That would work as follows:

```
BEGIN
   PERFORM function1();
   PERFORM function2();
   /* more work */
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT INTO log_table VALUES (...);
END;
```

Everything between the `BEGIN` and `EXCEPTION` will run in a subtransaction. If any exception is thrown, the whole subtransaction is rolled back and an error is logged.

Comment: yes, that what I did but with "if ... end if;" statement for each function.  None of them work when the exception is thrown.

Comment: The problem is if I do with "if ... end if" statement for each child function, even one of them is error, the main function posted all start ... end function successful.  If I make an error/type in the main function, it will thrown an error in the errorlog and stop without posting the start process, blah ...blah different with oracle procedure and even script converted from ora2pg and I have been fixed a lot to make it work.  It works if nothing error, that's not right if one of function and log has an error message.  Even I removed the "if ... end if" statement.

Comment: It would be good if you take a breath and some time and try to compose a description in plain, simple English. I cannot understand you.

Comment: I said I did try as same as you suggested yesterday and if any exception is thrown, there's no roll back at all.  The subtransaction is continuing run even one exception is thrown.  I want a whole substranaction is rolled back if one subtransaction is thrown.